# Scope handling in OAuth2 protocol

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, scopes

I have a general question regarding how scopes in the OAuth2 protocol are handled. For easy argumentation lets start with a concrete example:

Lets say I have an OAuth server A which I want to use in order to protect two RESTful APIs `R1` and `R2`. These two services have special scopes that they use to grant a user access to some protected resources. So lets say `R1` needs the scope `S1` and `R2` needs the scope `S2` in order to access some restricted resources.

Lets further assume that the OAuth server `A` makes also use of the scopes `email` and `profile`, they are needed to access the user data that the OAuth server itself manages.

Now here is what I'm having trouble to understand. As far as I can see the OAuth server `A` normally only knows how to handle the scopes that he itself uses (in this case `email` and `profile`). But what about the scopes that are required in order to access the restricted functionality on the two APIs (`R1` needs `S1` and `R2` needs `S2`)?

Do I have to register these scopes manually with the OAuth server (so that it knows that they exist and can grant them should that be needed)? That again would mean that I need to register all scopes of all the APIs that I want to protect/use using the OAuth server.

Are these assumptions correct? If I get something wrong here perhaps someone can help me by explaining how the entire scope handling is normally implemented. I tried to google oauth2 and scopes but there seems to be no good explanation of how exactly scopes are handled in the protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's the OAuth2 authorization server `A` responsability to issue access tokens, and that access tokens are granted with specific scopes, it sounds reasonable to have `A` be aware of of `S1` and `S2`.

It's not entirely necessary, `A` could treat scope as "opaque" strings and not care, but registering the scopes with `A` give you the ability to check that the scopes requested exist (and are not some random strings), as well as display a more meaningful message in the prompt displayed to the user during the authorization flow ("Do you allow "OAuth2 client" to access your R1 data which means blablabla" rather than "Do you grant access to S1").

Comment: So to wrap it up, it seems to be a good idea to implement functionality within the OAuth Server `A` that allows for managing scopes (CRUD). So the server really needs to know all the scopes that are needed by the protected services after all? Thanks for your answer!